# Read image with DevIL

Tags: opengl, devil

I have problems with reading an image with DevIL 1.7.8.
So far I know the following snippet should work:

```
ilInit();
ILuint ImageName;
ilGenImages(1, &ImageName);
ilBindImage(ImageName);
wchar_t* imgFilename = L"..\\..\\resources\\textures\\red.png"; 
ilLoadImage(imgFilename);
ILubyte* texture = ilGetData();
```

When I check the first pixels

```
for (int i=0; i<64; i++) cout << (int)texture[i] << endl;
```

I get a pretty random output. The picture is actually completely red.

As well I tried using ilut

```
ilutRenderer(ILUT_OPENGL);
GLuint t = ilutGLLoadImage(L"..\\..\\resources\\textures\\red.png");
```

But actually I can't even include the corresponding header file because within that header file il.h is linked which is supposed to be in a folder (\IL) that does not exist. Even when I create this folder and copy the needed header files into it I get compile errors.

Can anybody help me with DevIL?

Answer (score 0):

I am reading image and binding textures like this:

```
ilEnable(IL_ORIGIN_SET);
ilOriginFunc(IL_ORIGIN_LOWER_LEFT); // set [0,0] of texture to bottom left corner

ilImage image;
GLuint ind;
glGenTextures(1, &ind);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ind);
image.Load(L"<path>");//  or just name.format  be sure to have image in correct folder.
```

When rendering, you need to bind the correct texture first:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ind);
```

And then assign UV coordites of texture to vertexes:

```
glTexCoord2f(x1, y1);               
glVertex3f(x, y, z);
```

Do not forget to enable GL_TEXTURE_2D or whatever type you are using.